# HTML form target a new window using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, window

I want to use a form to post data in a new opened window. Here is my Jquery code:

```
url = "index.php?menu="+menu;
newWin = window.open(url, "windowViewProcess", 1024, 760, "status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes");
$('#form2').attr('target', 'windowViewProcess');
$('#form2').submit();
```

The form:

```
<form method="post" id="form2" name="form2" action="">
```

I have no idea why is not working. The new window opens but the data is not posted there.

I tried see the HTTP data using an HTTP profiler and the POST DATA property is empty, so no data is posted to the new window. Why?

Comment: I [can't reproduce](http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/23455988/) the problem you describe

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have a empty attribute action for the Form. You have to have the action attribute set for the Form tag.

action="**index.php**"

If you have this, it will submit the form with the Post data inside the form.

---

Suppose if you want to set the action attribute of the form dynamically, then you can add one line.

$('#form2').attr('target', 'windowViewProcess');

**$('#form2').attr('action', url);**

$('#form2').submit();

In this case you will have both the Post data as well as get data (menu) in the submitted form.